# Saboteur (1/2): Should the mine cards match like pieces on a puzzle?

Tags: saboteur-2, saboteur

When you play a card on your mine, can you put something that doesn't match as long as one part matches?

In the example below, the purple arrow shows the direction of play. So the three uncircled cards have been played. Is it legal to play the card circled in red? Note that it doesn't match a path of the card directly below it.

[image: Example cards]

Comment: The subject of your question and the body ask the question in opposite ways.  "Should the mine card match like pieces in a puzzle?"  and "When you play a card can you put something that doesn't match".  It would be better if these two versions of the question had the same answer.  Since you already have an answer that is "Yes" to the question in the subject I think you should change the first line of the body to something like "When you play a card are you forbidden to place a card that doesn't match one side even if it does match on another side?"

Comment: @EricNolan amended the title

Comment: I rolled back the edit as it changed the meaning of existing answers.

Comment: And I just changed your Yes to a No as it fixed existing answers :-D  @JoeW But whatever works for y'all! I just hope it's not approved by someone else!

Comment: That is why you should not be changing questions so much as it requires a lot of other things to change otherwise they end up being wrong.

Comment: I just followed @EricNolan's advice - I've now learned my lesson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes all edges should match up and connect to a path or have no connection at all.

https://www.amigo.games/content/ap/rule/18751-ur2%20Rules.pdf

> The basic rules of Saboteur still apply.
> Changes and additions to these rules are explained below

https://www.ultraboardgames.com/saboteur/game-rules.php

> All paths on the sides of the new card must fit with the other cards already in play, and they can never be played crosswise.

Comment: So, even those that are a dead end must connect, right? "must fit" is ambiguous to me - what is fit? Especially for a dead end... So the card in the circle cannot be played.

Comment: "must fit" means the edges with paths must find fits with other edges with paths and the edges without paths must find fits with other edges without paths.

Comment: @ParibusCeteris Every side that has a path must match up to another side that has a path even if it is just a dead end. You can't have one side of a card with a path touch a side of a card without a path.

Comment: @JoeW Unfortunately the asker changed the question in the subject line so that the first word of your answer should be "No" instead of "Yes"

Comment: @EricNolan Questions should not be edited in a manner that would invalidate existing answers and the edit has been rolled back.